d.jsx is not a function- react production build
React Production Build:

My package.json file
{
  "name": "user-dahsboard",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.7.5",
    "bootstrap": "4.6",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.11.3",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.10.4",
    "react-colorful": "^5.6.1",
    "react-cropper": "^2.3.3",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-toastify": "^10.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@eslint/js": "^9.9.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.3.1",
    "eslint": "^9.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.35.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^5.1.0-rc.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.9",
    "globals": "^15.9.0",
    "vite": "^5.4.1"
  }
}


The issue occurs here
 <Alert variant="light" role="alert">
                                <span><span>Your profile is live:</span> <a href={Link} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">{Link}</a></span>
                                <Button variant="primary" className="float-right btn-sm" data-link={Link} onClick={handleCopyLink}>Copy your URL</Button>
                            </Alert>

where ever i have used plain html inside the React-bootstrap markup, its trigering error once the build file is generated. works fine with npm run dev.
This is my vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
})

Please help me what i am missing, I'am new to react family.
